# $f$ is differentiable convex function and $x_0$ is a critical point for f

Tags: convex-analysis

I have the following theorem:
Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable function. Then $f$ is convex if and only if
$f(y)\geq f(x)+f'(x)(y-x)$ for every $x,y\in (a,b)$

Then i am given the following:
Suppose that $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable convex function and $x_0\in (a,b)$ is a critical point for $f$. What can you say about $x_0$ using the theorem.

This seems like a pretty simple question but i'm honestly not sure what i'm supposed to answer. Anyone got any ideas what might be good to say here? anything is appreciated

Comment: Do you have any ideas?  What does it mean for $x_{0}$ to be a critical point?

Comment: If $f'(x_0) = 0$ then $f(y) \ge f(x_0)$ for all appropriate $y$.